# is there a way to save time writing a repeated event procedures, and do it in a function or class

Tags: vba, ms-access, event-handling, controls

I have multiple controls in a form in MS. Access, that when they receive focus the border width and color would change, just to make my end user see where is the focus at.

I tried so many ways, I found on the net, but nothing seems to work.

This is the event procedure I'm trying to solve, and I have more than 16 on that in the form, repeating the same code :(

I'm repeating this code block many times, and I'm sure there is a way to make my coding improve, by minimizing this number by a function or class.
I really need your help. please

```
Private Sub team_Enter()
    team.BorderWidth = 3
    team.BorderColor = RGB(80, 234, 240)
End Sub

Private Sub team_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    team.BorderWidth = 0
    team.BorderColor = RGB(166, 166, 166)
End Sub
```

Comment: Conditional Formatting can set background color and font color when textbox or combobox has focus. No VBA needed.

Comment: Can have a procedure that receives control name as an argument. Still need Enter and Exit events for each control. However, the procedure can be a function that is called directly from the event property. One procedure can serve with arguments for control name (or control object) and the action ("enter", "exit"). Not sure there really is an advantage for such short procedure as you still need to set up event code for each control. When you have this 'generic' procedure code with issue, post question.

Comment: Google "VBA control array" for the typical approach to use cases like this.

Comment: Eg: https://www.msaccesstips.com/2019/08/withevents-and-all-form-control-types.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `WithEvents` using a collection of your controls.

See my demo on **GitHub**: [VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme).

Form module:

```vb
' Form to display the Windows Phone 7.5/8.0 colour theme.
' Also works as a basic example of implementing WithEvents for a form.
' 2017-04-19. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.


Private ControlCollection   As Collection

Private Sub Form_Load()

    ' Load events for all colour value textboxes.
    
    Dim EventProcedure  As ClassTextboxSelect
    Dim Control         As Access.Control
    
    Set ControlCollection = New Collection
    
    For Each Control In Me.Controls
        If Control.ControlType = acTextBox Then
            Set EventProcedure = New ClassTextboxSelect
            EventProcedure.Initialize Control
            ControlCollection.Add EventProcedure, Control.Name
        End If
    Next
    
    Set EventProcedure = Nothing
    Set Control = Nothing
    
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim Index   As Integer
    
    ' Set colour palette.
    For Index = 0 To 20
        Me("Box" & CStr(Index + 1)).BackColor = PaletteColor(Index)
        Me("Name" & CStr(Index + 1)).Value = LiteralWpThemeColor(PaletteColor(Index))
        Me("Css" & CStr(Index + 1)).Value = RGBHex(PaletteColor(Index))
        Me("Vba" & CStr(Index + 1)).Value = PaletteColor(Index)
        Me("Hex" & CStr(Index + 1)).Value = "&H" & Hex(PaletteColor(Index))
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    ' Unload events for all colour value textboxes.
    
    Dim EventProcedure  As ClassTextboxSelect
    
    For Each EventProcedure In ControlCollection
        EventProcedure.Terminate
    Next
    
    Set EventProcedure = Nothing
    Set ControlCollection = Nothing

End Sub
```

The class:

```vb
' Helper class for form Palette for event handling of textboxes.
' 2017-04-19. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' Version 1.0.0
' License: MIT.

' *

Private Const EventProcedure    As String = "[Event Procedure]"

Private WithEvents ClassTextBox As Access.TextBox
Attribute ClassTextBox.VB_VarHelpID = -1

Public Sub Initialize(ByRef TextBox As Access.TextBox)

    Set ClassTextBox = TextBox
    
    ClassTextBox.OnClick = EventProcedure
    
End Sub

Public Sub Terminate()

    Set ClassTextBox = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub ClassTextBox_Click()

    ' Select full content.
    ClassTextBox.SelStart = 0
    ClassTextBox.SelLength = Len(ClassTextBox.Value)
    ' Display the clicked value.
    ClassTextBox.Parent!CopyClicked.Value = ClassTextBox.Value
    ' Copy the clicked value to the clipboard.
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy

End Sub
```

Snip:

[image]